# Looping through a Set of Variables with defined values

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a set of values I'm trying to enter into a pdf automatically.  It starts by opening the pdf and using the sendkeys to tab through set textboxes within the pdf.  I'm trying to loop this sendkeys function while using the set variables I have defined  (D1,D2,D3,etc.).

What I have/have tried is not working and I can't seem to figure out how to define the list I'm going through (shown with the XXXXX).

Code is shown below:

```
Sub CreatePDFForms()
Dim PDFTemplateFile, NewPDFName, SavePDFFldr, Desc As String
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long

With Sheet1
LastRow = .Range("A999").End(xlUp).Row    
PDFTemplateFile = .Range("F2").Value       
SavePDFFldr = .Range("F4").Value           
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PDFTemplateFile
Application.Wait Now + 0.000004

For CustRow = 13 To 13 ' LastRow
D1 = .Range("L" & CustRow).Value        
D2 = .Range("B" & CustRow).Value          
D3 = .Range("AC" & CustRow).Value
D4 = .Range("C" & CustRow).Value
D5 = .Range("Y" & CustRow).Value
D6 = .Range("AB" & CustRow).Value
D7 = .Range("Z" & CustRow).Value
D8 = .Range("U" & CustRow).Value
'D9 = .Range("AA" & CustRow).Value
'D10 = .Range("AA" & CustRow).Value

Description = D4                      

DataEntry = XXXXX(D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8)

For DataEntry = 1 To 8

Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys DataEntry, True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001

Next DataEntry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataEntry = Array(D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8)

For Each e in DataEntry 

    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys e, True
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001

Next e
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.Thank you!